# Is a portable jump starter dangerous?

Tags: safety, camping

Like many campers, I bought a portable jump starter, which contains liquids and gases. In what situation does it get dangerous?

Can I simply carry this portable charger along with all my camping gear such as butane gases and stove?

Can it be stored under hot/cold weather?

Comment: Most portable jump starters I've seen are just a Li-ion battery pack w/ an onboard charger. Is that what you have?

Comment: @jrodatus I have http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B002X6VXL4?redirect=true&ref_=s9_simh_gw_p263_d0_i2

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the safety of a battery and associated electronics. It is as common in a city as in the outdoors and is not directly related to the outdoors.

Comment: Unspecified but it's probably Li-ion or lead-acid. A rental yard I worked at kept a bunch of these (similar) in the shop, exposed to outdoor air, dirt, grease, grime, humidity, temperature-- they are pretty hardy. _Keep it charged_, don't let it get rained on, or exposed to excessive moisture, don't drop it from a height, and [only charge between 0 to 45 °C, only discharge between -20 to 50 °C](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_at_high_and_low_temperatures). Given those cond., my limited experience suggests it'll be fine.

Comment: I would say it's relevant as it is a necessary item to take to remote areas in a vehicle.  Whether it exists in urban and back country locals is irrelevant.  Under that logic gas stove safety would also be off topic and should be migrated.

Comment: @PaulD I think a household natural gas stove certainly would be offtopic, as where a propane portable camping one would not. On the stackexchange site I spend the most time on, we generally opt for "it has to be *directly* related to [our subject]", not just "well it could be...", which basically everything *can* be related to everything else if you stretch your mind far enough. I could put a couch in a tree, right? So couches are ontopic outdoors now. My logic anyway, hence my vote. Not trying to convince anyone if they don't agree with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is safe as long as you store and transport sensibly.

@jrodatus listed a few points:

- keep it charged
- don't get it wet
- don't drop it
- only charge within the correct temperature range

But additionally, especially if it is in with metal objects, you must make sure it does not get shorted out when switched on. If you accidentally allow a screwdriver or ice-axe or anything metal to short the terminals, you could suddenly discover a very effective fire starter in your kit bag!